# Different dummy variable types in regression

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I am running ols regressions with firms from different countries and different industries. I want to control for both country and industry membership of each firm. Say I have 1,...,N countries and 1,...,M industries. How many dummy variables do I need to avoid the dummy trap? 
I am using Matlab, so I have to manually set up all regressors.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: No, its not a question from a course or textbook. However, I assume that I only need N-1 country dummies and M-1 industry dummies. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you explain to the rest of us what the dummy trap is?

Comment: What is your sample size?  How many countries do you have and how many different industries?